# Reading XM2VTS image database from "bindata file format" in Python or (MATLAB)

Tags: python, matlab, binary, multiclass-classification

I can not read the XM2VTS database (https://www.idiap.ch/resource/faceverif/data/xm2vts/face32x40-eyecenter.tar.gz) as 40x32 (or 32x40) grayscale images.

Each file is 10248 Bytes = 8 + (32 x 40 x 8).

Python

```
import numpy as np
A=np.fromfile("000_1_1.bindata", dtype=np.uint8)
print(A.shape)
```

MATLAB

```
fileID = fopen('000_1_1.bindata');
A = fread(fileID,'uint8');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


I0=(np.fromfile('000_1_1.bindata','float32'))
I0=I0[2:]
I0 =I0.reshape(80, 32)

I=I0[:40,:]
plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you provide explanation in your answer.